# Are there reports on Watched and Ignored Tags in Stack Overflow Enterprise?

Tags: support, tags, moderator-tools, stack-overflow-enterprise

I searched through the moderator tools and reports and did not find any metrics on Watched and Ignored Tags. Does this exist and I'm not seeing it?

This would be useful for understanding which topics have the most dedicated users, and which topics are not getting the support they need. It could also be used for generating participation in Stack by soliciting SMEs to watch the tags of their expertise.

It might also indicate whether users understand this feature exists or not.

Comment: You would not only want to know how much each tag was watched or ignored but also correlations, i.e. which tags are watched together, which tags are ignored together, which tags are watched together with other ignored tags, ... . On the other hand, can't the general participation not also be estimated from the tag activity, like the number of questions and answers or views in each tag?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [tag:support] questions about Stack Overflow Enterprise are outside of the scope of Meta Stack Overflow per precedent at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416722/3750257.